# Meaning of some Paint constants in Android

Tags: android, text, constants, paint

There are a few Paint constant in Android about which I couldn't find much info. Could anyone help me with a bit of explanation about those flags:

- LINEAR_TEXT_FLAG
- SUBPIXEL_TEXT_FLAG
- FILTER_BITMAP_FLAG

Is 'subpixel' mode something close to ClearType or is it something altogether different?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

SUBPIXEL is indeed for sub-pixel antialiasing, which is currently not supported on Android. Setting this flag will have no effect. FILTER_BITMAP is used to apply bilinear filtering to bitmaps when they are transformed (scaled for instance.) It's usually a good idea to enable FILTER_BITMAP unless speed matters (much) more than quality. LINEAR_TEXT is used to draw text at a 64px text size with a scale factor set to your textSize/64.

Comment: Thanks, Romain! Could you explain a bit more about the LINEAR_TEXT flag? I mean, I still don't understand why one would need to use it. Also there's that in the docs, for the LINEAR_TEXT_FLAG constant they say 'bit mask for the flag enabling linear-text (no caching)'. Do you know what is that 'caching' here they are talking about?

Comment: By the way, I am very happy to be talking directly to a developer from the Android team!

Comment: Text rendering uses a font cache containing bitmap representations of each glyph the application needs. Linear text basically lets you skip the font cache.